# Clicking the links having same link text in a loop using Seleneium webdriver in Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using following code to scroll the page and follow the users on quora (Link to the page : http://www.quora.com/Kevin-Rose/followers), certain number of users are loaded after scrolling down, i am using the code given below :

```
# find all the follow buttons that are loaded
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Follow')]")

#number of users loaded
no_of_followers = len(button)

#execute the code till all the users are followed
while(no_of_followers > 0):

    count = 0
    #follow all the users loaded by clicking follow button in a loop 
    while(count < no_of_followers):

        button[count].click()
        time.sleep(30)
        print count
        count = count + 1

    #scroll down        
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(30)'
    #find newly loaded users
    button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Follow')]")
    time.sleep(30)
    #tracking no of users left unfollowed
    no_of_followers = len(button)
```

I am getting following error:

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM' ; Stacktrace:

**Edit 1**: I tried using `find_element_by_link _text`, but apparently output object of the function is not a list of links which can be iterated.

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem is @ button[count].click().
I suggest you to use a for loop instead of while and increament that with an iterator.

Do something like

//you basically need to click on the first item all the time. The iterator should only control the number of iteration

```
 Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("Your Xpath")).Click();
```

Sorry, not an expert on python.

Comment: Actually I am clicking on all the users that are on the page not just the first user. I am using no_of_followers variable for keeping track of number of users that are loaded. Will you please explain what difference for loop will make?

Comment: well, I guess you should be able to user while loop as well but, not button[count].click()

Comment: I also tried "driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Follow')][count]").click()" ..even that is not working

Comment: well, I guess you should be able to use while loop as well but, not button[count].click(). The reason behind this is as soon as you scroll down the elements you found with button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Follow')]") are detached from DOM and that returns staleelement ref exception. In order to avoid that you need to find the element on the fly. And, the reason you always want to click the first item is as soon as you click follow the text changes to following and you want to click the first item on the page which has follow text.

Comment: Bottom line is, use while or for loop to control your scrolling and   use a proper selector to click on first follow button

Comment: if this line returns you a colection use driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Follow')][0]").click() to always click the first item

Comment: okay..this was helpful. That explains why my loop worked only once. Thanks.

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept this is as an answer